# Publish a latched message in rosjava

Tags: ros, latch, rosjava, publisher, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to publish a latched message in rosjava so that my arduino only receives a command when it is different than the preivous one. Currently, it is constantly polling and that makes my program not to work.

In roscpp, I know that you can set the boolean latch = true.

Is there an equivalent in rosjava?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12226/publish-a-latched-message-in-rosjava/) by [Tuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/854/tuan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2011-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, see the javadoc here: http://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava/doc/org/ros/node/topic/Publisher.html#setLatchMode(boolean)

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2011-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0